# Cfilter match from begginning of line

Tags: quickfix

Say I have entries like this in the quickfix window:

```
manage.py|7 col 54| os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'dist.plug.from.settings')
project/urls.py|29 col 6| from dist.plug.apps import PlugConfig
project/urls.py|30 col 6| from dist.plug.urls import dist_urlpatterns
project/wsgi.py|15 col 50| os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'dist.plug.from.settings')
config/cfg3_distro.py|15 col 10| from dist.plug.cfg1_custom import Custom
apps_web/csslib/cprops.py|5 col 6| from dist.plug.theme import theme
core/accounts/admin.py|10 col 6| from dist.plug.user import UserAdminMixin
core/accounts/models.py|4 col 6| from dist.plug.user import UserMixin
core/accounts/utils.py|1 col 6| from dist.plug.user import UserMixin
```

I wish to keep all entries that don't start with `from`.

`:h Cfilter` does not explain whether the filter matches the whole line (i.e. file name, line/col and line), or just the line.
So I tried both ways but neither is working for me:

If it matches the whole line I tried:

- `:Cfilter! /| from/` matches nothing (all remain)
- `:Cfilter! /\| from/` matches everything (nothing remains)

If it matches just the line from the file, I tried:

- `:Cfilter! /^from/` matches some (some starting with `from` are removed, but some with `from` in the start remain, not sure what it did)
- `:Cfilter! /\^from/` matches nothing (all remain)

Confused as to whats going on, I must be missing something.

Comment: Good question, though in this case `:Cfilter! import` might be simpler

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing all the entries that don't start with `from`, use `Cfilter` (without `!`) to keep all the entries that start with `from`.

> The |:Cfilter| command creates a new quickfix list from the entries
> matching {pat} in the current quickfix list. {pat} is a Vim
> |regular-expression| pattern. Both the file name and the text of the
> entries are matched against {pat}. **If the optional ! is supplied, then
> the entries not matching {pat} are used.** The pattern can be optionally
> enclosed using one of the following

As for the format, this should work correctly: `:Cfilter /^from/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry I confused myself. I wish to Keep entries that start with from (I corrected it now).  With regards to `:Cfilter /^from/` shoudl work, that is interesting.

Comment: No problem! And yes, I think that should work :)

Comment: Strange that `:Cfilter /^from/` does not work fo rme, its matches nothing (all entries remain)

Comment: Are you sure there is not an extra space or another character that changes your quickfix input? I tried to replicate your quickfix list and it seems to be working. Before https://i.imgur.com/43qK3eQ.png and after https://i.imgur.com/oX2Zo7S.png